# Juju bootstrap - 403 Forbidden "not allowed to start up this node"

Tags: juju

I try to deploy MAAS/Juju for the first time and I have some problems when i try to bootstrap JuJu.

Here's my errors :

```
root@maas-server:~/.juju# juju bootstrap
Launching instance
WARNING picked arbitrary tools &{"1.18.4-precise-amd64" "https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.18.4-precise-amd64.tgz" "fa87616011cf2fbc7f25a646b59070aa8df1e54d6edfd279281894e9c3fbcc4d" %!q(int64=5360167)}
ERROR bootstrap failed: cannot start bootstrap instance: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 403 FORBIDDEN (You are not allowed to start up this node.)
Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
ERROR cannot start bootstrap instance: gomaasapi: got error back from server: 403 FORBIDDEN (You are not allowed to start up this node.)
```

here's my environments.yaml

```
environments:
  vb-maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: http://10.0.0.1:80/MAAS
    maas-oauth: "BMpXsbZDqP4xUvyYJu:8ctDLuRsAc7UNj7T2M:YwBHUDXUEvhzuXZpHBky9p8wmsyFdMCL"
    admin-secret: super-secret-made-up-admin-key
    default-series: precise
    authorized-keys-path: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Ubuntu serve (maas server) is a 14.04 version.
Juju : 1.18.1-trusty-amd64
MAAS : 1.5.2+bzr2282-0ubuntu

I have 2 nodes "ready".
Considering the "403 error", I assume there is a problem with a key, password or privilege... I deleted MAAS-key and re-generate a another one, no change.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Looking at documentation I noticed that maas-server is reported with ' char: `maas-server: 'httpd://10.0.0.1:80/MAAS'`. I don't know if this is the problem, but it simple to try.

Comment: No replace "http" by "httpd" doesn't change anything. it just adds another error because "httpd" isn't a supported protocol.
Can you link the page where you found this information ?

Comment: Oh! sorry I was wrong in typing! This the right: `maas-server: 'http://10.0.0.1:80/MAAS'` and this is the [link](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/juju-quick-start.html) but I think you already view.

Comment: I tried replace " by ', replace IP by hostname etc but as expected, doesn't change anything...

Comment: Have you added an SSH key to your MAAS profile?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. I didn't specify a power type for my nodes. My nodes are vm and I didn't understand what the doc want me to do with the virsh type. So I chose "WOL". And for the time being, it works. Juju is deployed and I can deploy openstack services on my nodes.

Thx everyone for the help.